# Python regex replace text starting and ending with specific phrases

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, replace

I want to replace text starting with `<img>` and ending with `</img>`.
Im just starting with regex stuff.

I have tried below code.

Final result should be:

input:

```
"New Year's Eve <img>scr=[...]</img>, New Year's Day (Observed)"
```

output:

```
"New Year's Eve [image placeholder], New Year's Day (Observed)"
```

Code sample

```
import re
input = [
    "Independence Day (Observed)",
    "Another Christmas Eve, Christmas Day (Observed)",
    "New Year's Eve <img>scr=[...]</img>, New Year's Day (Observed)",
    "Martin Luther King, Jr. <img>scr=[...]</img> Day"
]
for holiday in input:
    print(re.sub(r'\b<img>\b', '[image placeholder]', holiday))`
```

Comment: Are you sure the image tags look like that? Surely they would be more likely to look like this: `<img src="some/path/foo.jpg">...</img>` or `<img src="some/path/foo.jpg" />`.

Comment: Of course, my fault, I retyped the code because I was away from my pc. Thank you for pointing out the obvious typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace all the code between the opening and closing tag:

```
import re
input = [
    "Independence Day (Observed)",
    "Another Christmas Eve, Christmas Day (Observed)",
    "New Year's Eve <img>scr=[...]</img>, New Year's Day (Observed)"
    "Martin Luther King, Jr. <img>scr=[...]</img> Day"
]
for holiday in input:
    print(re.sub(r'<img>.*?</img>', '[image placeholder]', holiday))
```

Output:

```
Independence Day (Observed)
Another Christmas Eve, Christmas Day (Observed)
New Year's Eve [image placeholder], New Year's Day (Observed)
Martin Luther King, Jr. [image placeholder] Day
```

The regex matches text starting with `<img>` and ending with `</img>` with anything in between `.*?`. `?` makes it match non greedily, so that it will match until the first closing tag that follows the opening tag - that allows it to replace every pair of tags correctly if there are several in the same  input text.